# C++ templates, default argument as a method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, std

For this implementation of selection sort:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Compare>
void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Compare comp) {
    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        auto min = i;
        for (auto j = i + 1; j != end; ++j) {
            if (comp(*j, *min)) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        std::swap(*min, *i);
    }
}
```

How should I modify it so that `Compare comp` should be [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) method if last parameter is skipped for sort method?

I tried function overloading by introducing another method:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    sort(begin, end, std::less<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>());
}
```

But it gave errors like:

```
In file included from ../src/selection_sort_demo.cpp:1:
../include/selection_sort.hpp:24:29: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?
        sort(begin, end, std::less<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>());
                                   ^
                                   typename 
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_function.h:380:21: note: template parameter is declared here
  template<typename _Tp>
                    ^
In file included from ../src/selection_sort_demo.cpp:1:
../include/selection_sort.hpp:24:2: error: call to 'sort' is ambiguous
        sort(begin, end, std::less<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>());
        ^~~~
../src/selection_sort_demo.cpp:22:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'selection::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >' requested here
        selection::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4727:5: note: candidate function [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _Compare = std::less<int>]
    sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
    ^
../include/selection_sort.hpp:7:6: note: candidate function [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, Compare = std::less<int>]
void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Compare comp)
     ^
2 errors generated.
[2/4] Compiling cpp object 'test/testexe@exe/selection_sort_test.cpp.o'
FAILED: test/testexe@exe/selection_sort_test.cpp.o 
clang++  '-Itest/testexe@exe' '-Itest' '-I../test' '-I../include' '-Wall' '-Winvalid-pch' '-Wnon-virtual-dtor' '-std=c++14' '-O0' '-g' '-pthread' '-MMD' '-MQ' 'test/testexe@exe/selection_sort_test.cpp.o' '-MF' 'test/testexe@exe/selection_sort_test.cpp.o.d' -o 'test/testexe@exe/selection_sort_test.cpp.o' -c ../test/selection_sort_test.cpp
In file included from ../test/selection_sort_test.cpp:2:
../include/selection_sort.hpp:24:29: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?
        sort(begin, end, std::less<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>());
                                   ^
                                   typename 
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_function.h:380:21: note: template parameter is declared here
  template<typename _Tp>
                    ^
In file included from ../test/selection_sort_test.cpp:2:
../include/selection_sort.hpp:24:2: error: call to 'sort' is ambiguous
        sort(begin, end, std::less<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>());
        ^~~~
../test/selection_sort_test.cpp:17:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'selection::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >' requested here
        selection::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4727:5: note: candidate function [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _Compare = std::less<int>]
    sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
    ^
../include/selection_sort.hpp:7:6: note: candidate function [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, Compare = std::less<int>]
void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Compare comp)
     ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: `typename Iterator` instead of `Iterator` ?

Comment: [Related Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1782465)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it's c++14:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Compare = std::less<> >
void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Compare comp = Compare())
{
    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        auto min = i;
        for (auto j = i + 1; j != end; ++j) {
            if (comp(*j, *min)) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        std::swap(*min, *i);
    }
}
```

c++11:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Compare = std::less< typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type > >
void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Compare comp = Compare())
{
    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        auto min = i;
        for (auto j = i + 1; j != end; ++j) {
            if (comp(*j, *min)) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        std::swap(*min, *i);
    }
}
```

Explanation:

We have to offer the compiler both a default type in the template argument list and a default function argument list.

For explanation of std::less<> since c++14 see:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Comment: Hey, spaces are not needed after less<>.

Comment: @PeterK you and the compiler might not need them, but I do! :-)

Comment: If you go through `iterator_traits` instead of using `Iterator::`, the code will work with all iterators (including pointers).

Comment: @Angew Awesome suggestion.  I deleted my answer since using that with this answer would be much better.

Comment: @RichardHodges great answer. One small question though, why do I've to write this part - `Compare comp = Compare()` instead of just `Compare comp` like other args are written. Is it always done with default template args?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal if you don't add the `= Compare()` you're not providing a default function argument, so you'd have to supply it at the call site.

Comment: @RichardHodges I thought it was done with `typename Compare = std::less<>`, nvm I'll read about it.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal `typename Compare = std::less<>` provides a default *template argument* for the *template parameter.* `Compare comp = Compare()` provides a default *function argument* for the *function parameter.* Without the latter, you'd still have to provide a function argument when calling the function, but (thanks to the default template argument), its type would default to `std::less<>` if it wasn't deducible (such as if you used `{}`).

Answer (score 5):

You were right, but forgot the `typename` keyword. Check this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    sort(begin, end, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>());
}
```

Probably you wanted default template argument, but this works too.

Comment: How is it ambiguous? The arity is different.

Comment: sorry it's just my MSVC picking up `std::sort` through ADL

Comment: @Nazar554 I do have my own namespace in my code, excluded here for simplicity.